# How to get corresponding value to a button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want the value of button but instead I want the value of a span inside a div which corresponds to that button. I have a model in which buttons correspond to a div. [image]

For example here you can see there are 3 buttons that correspond to each assignment.

Whenever a user clicks Assign button I need to return the value of the title span for example if someone clicks assign on first, it should print "English UOI 1" in the console.

The html code wraps up like this -

```
<div class="assignment-wrapper">
    <div class="assignment-title"><span class="assignment-name">English UOI 1</span><span>15-06-2021</span></div>
    <div class="assignment-functions">
        <div class="assign-task assignment-function-btn">Assign</div>
        <div class="update-task assignment-function-btn">Update</div>
        <div class="view-results assignment-function-btn">Results</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this is the example for structure but I would be doing this using javascript, I have retrieved data for database an I need to present each assignment in a table form.

If you have a better model you can suggest changes.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for the sibling of the parent of the button div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target up the element tree 2 parents and then back down two children and get the spans textContent.

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.assignment-function-btn')

function getValue(e){
  let target = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].children[0]
  console.log(target.textContent)
}

btn.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', getValue)
})
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.assignment-function-btn {
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <div class="assignment-wrapper row">
    <div class="assignment-title">
       <span class="assignment-name">English UOI 1</span>    
       <span>15-06-2021</span>
    </div>
    <div class="assignment-functions row">
        <div class="assign-task assignment-function-btn">Assign</div>
        <div class="update-task assignment-function-btn">Update</div>
        <div class="view-results assignment-function-btn">Results</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**or...**

If each of these classes per say, has its own line with the three buttons for each title/class, you could code a *dataset* attribute into the buttons parent element that represents the title/class that button is being used for. *See my second snippit for that example...*

**Using dataset attribute:**

In your HTML you add a data attribute like `data-class-name="English UOI 1"` to the direct parent element of your buttons. Then use the event target + parentNode to get the `e.target.parentNode.dataset.className`.

`className` is javascript camel-case for `class-name`.

```html
    <div class="assignment-title">
      <span class="assignment-name">English UOI 1</span>
      <span>15-06-2021</span>
    </div>
    <!--/ Here we add the data attribute data-class-name="English UOI 1" /-->
    <div data-class-name="English UOI 1" class="assignment-functions row">
      <div class="assign-task assignment-function-btn">Assign</div>
      <div class="update-task assignment-function-btn">Update</div>
      <div class="view-results assignment-function-btn">Results</div>
    </div>
```

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.assignment-function-btn')

function getValue(e) {
  let target = e.target.parentNode
  console.log(target.dataset.className)
}

btn.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', getValue)
})
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.assignment-title {
  flex: auto;
}

.assignment-function-btn {
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="assignment-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="assignment-title">
      <span class="assignment-name">English UOI 1</span>
      <span>15-06-2021</span>
    </div>
    <div data-class-name="English UOI 1" class="assignment-functions row">
      <div class="assign-task assignment-function-btn">Assign</div>
      <div class="update-task assignment-function-btn">Update</div>
      <div class="view-results assignment-function-btn">Results</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="assignment-title">
      <span class="assignment-name">Social Sciences</span>
      <span>23-06-2021</span>
    </div>
    <div data-class-name="Social Sciences" class="assignment-functions row">
      <div class="assign-task assignment-function-btn">Assign</div>
      <div class="update-task assignment-function-btn">Update</div>
      <div class="view-results assignment-function-btn">Results</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="assignment-title">
      <span class="assignment-name">Concepts of Algebra</span>
      <span>26-06-2021</span>
    </div>
    <div data-class-name="Concepts of Algebra" class="assignment-functions row">
      <div class="assign-task assignment-function-btn">Assign</div>
      <div class="update-task assignment-function-btn">Update</div>
      <div class="view-results assignment-function-btn">Results</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking about something like dataset but wasn't sure if that would work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.closest` to grab the `.assignment-wrapper` up the DOM tree and then, within the wrapper, find the `.assignment-name` element. Then grab its `innerText`.

Edit: Also, I strongly recommend using `button` elements for button behavior for accessibility purposes.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".assign-task");
btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const wrapper = e.target.closest(".assignment-wrapper");
  const assignment = wrapper.querySelector(".assignment-name");
  console.log(assignment.innerText);
})
```

```html
<div class="assignment-wrapper">
    <div class="assignment-title"><span class="assignment-name">English UOI 1</span><span>15-06-2021</span></div>
    <div class="assignment-functions">
        <button class="assign-task assignment-function-btn">Assign</button>
        <button class="update-task assignment-function-btn">Update</button>
        <button class="view-results assignment-function-btn">Results</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- what i understand of you that you wants to get the text of `.assignment-title span` blongs to the parent of this button

> Here's Example

```
var assignTask = document.getElementsByClassName('assign-task');
for(var i = 0; i < assignTask.length; i++) {
   assignTask[i].addEventListener('click',function() {
      var text = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('assignment-name')[0].innerText;
      console.log(text)
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below

```html
    <div class="assignment-wrapper">
      <div class="assignment-title">
        <span class="assignment-name">English UOI 1</span
        ><span>15-06-2021</span>
      </div>
      <div class="assignment-functions">
        <div class="assign-task assignment-function-btn">Assign</div>
        <div class="update-task assignment-function-btn">Update</div>
        <div class="view-results assignment-function-btn">Results</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      function handleButtonClick(event) {
        const buttonType = event.target.innerText;
        const assignmentName = event.target
          .closest(".assignment-wrapper")
          .querySelector(".assignment-name").innerText;
        console.log(`${assignmentName} -> ${buttonType}`);
      }

      document
        .querySelectorAll(".assignment-function-btn")
        .forEach((ele) => ele.addEventListener("click", handleButtonClick));
    </script>
```